# pyscreenshot module not working on run, PIL module not existing

Tags: python

I've imported the pyscreenshot module, but when I run code with it, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfilepaththatiwontshow", line 7, in <module>
    import pyscreenshot
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyscreenshot.childproc import childprocess_backend_version
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\childproc.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyscreenshot.imcodec import codec
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\imcodec.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I've checked twice and the pyscreenshot module is installed and tried running

```
pip install PIL
```

but apparently it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to its docs, **[Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)**:

> Pillow is the friendly PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors

This library is a drop-in replacement for PIL, which is no longer available or supported. To install `pillow`, use:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install pillow
```

Comment: This is pretty much a link-only answer. You should probably add to it. The system or a user flagged it for deletion review.

Comment: @Tim Sorry for the low quality answer, from now on I will definitely try to answer in detail like scnerd's answer.